# compare string before inserting into set c++

Tags: c++, set

Im trying to compare string before inserting to my set by comparing the length of the string. The shortest string should be inserted first. I dont know whats going on but some of the words are not on the set.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct compare {
    bool operator() (const string& a, const string& b) const{
        return a.size() < b.size();
    }
};

template<typename T>
void print(const T& t){
    for(auto& it : t)
        cout << it << endl;
}

int main() {    
    string word;
    set<string, compare> c;

    while(cin >> word)
        c.insert(word);

    print(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the test words to be inserted

```
Apple
Apricots
Avocado
Durian
Fig
Tangerine/Clementine
Kumquat
Lemon
Pear
Prunes
Raspberries
Strawberries
Watermelon
```

and here is the OUTPUT

```
Fig
Pear
Apple
Durian
Avocado
Apricots
Watermelon
Raspberries
Strawberries
Tangerine/Clementine
```

It works as expected, but apparently some words are missing
like:

```
Kumquat
Lemon
Prunes
```

Comment: Many people have explained the error with your code. But, if you care about the order of elements, std::set is not the right structure.

Comment: @bendervader I see, I am kind of new to c++, and i am not that familiar with the data structure. Yes I do can with the order of elements in my program, can you suggest a better data structure to use?

Comment: @bendervader That's not true -- std::sets are ordered. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set "std::set is an associative container that contains a *sorted* set of unique objects of type Key."

Comment: @alecb you are right. I meant to say the order of insertion is not important. A tree structure is by definition ordered. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step solving this should be to simplify, in this case, remove the input as a potential cause. Doing this reveals that the problem isn't caused by the source of the data. So lets see if the values ever get stored:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct compare {
    bool operator() (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const{
        return a.size() < b.size();
    }
};

template<typename T>
void print(const T& t){
    for(auto& it : t)
        std::cout << it << "\n";
}

template<typename T>
void insert(T& t, const char* value)
{
    t.insert(value);
    std::cout << "After inserting " << value << "\n";
    print(t);
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {    
    std::set<std::string, compare> c;

    insert(c, "Apple");
    insert(c, "Apricots");
    insert(c, "Avocado");
    insert(c, "Durian");
    insert(c, "Fig");
    insert(c, "Tangerine/Clementine");
    insert(c, "Kumquat");
    insert(c, "Lemon");
    insert(c, "Pear");
    insert(c, "Prunes");
    insert(c, "Raspberries");
    insert(c, "Strawberries");
    insert(c, "Watermelon");

    print(c);

    return 0;
}
```

The values don't get stored, but it seems likely we can home in on the problem:

```
    insert(c, "Apple");
    insert(c, "Lemon");
```

http://ideone.com/aGZOIN

`std::set::insert` returns some information that might be useful: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/

```
    auto result = t.insert(value);
```

and we're interested in result.second. It will be true (1) for a successful insert, or false (0) for a failure.

http://ideone.com/wP4CaG

```
After inserting Apple. inserted? 1
Apple

After inserting Lemon. inserted? 0
Apple
```

Your comparison operator is causing the set to think these two values are equal. `std::set` determines equivalence by using the `<` operator twice:

```
if (!cmp(a, b))
    if (!cmp(b, a))
        // equal;
```

You may want to use:

```
struct compare {
    bool operator() (const string& a, const string& b) const{
        if (a.size() < b.size())
            return true;
        if (a.size() == b.size() && a.compare(b) < 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct compare {
    bool operator() (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const{
        if (a.size() < b.size())
            return true;
        if (a.size() == b.size() && a.compare(b) < 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void print(const T& t){
    for(auto& it : t)
        std::cout << it << "\n";
}

template<typename T>
void insert(T& t, const char* value)
{
    auto result = t.insert(value);
    std::cout << "After inserting " << value << ". inserted? " << result.second << "\n";
    print(t);
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {    
    std::set<std::string, compare> c;

    insert(c, "Apple");
    insert(c, "Lemon");
    insert(c, "Fig");
    insert(c, "Kumquat");

    print(c);

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/Vs5p0i

Output:

```
After inserting Apple. inserted? 1
Apple

After inserting Lemon. inserted? 1
Apple
Lemon

After inserting Fig. inserted? 1
Fig
Apple
Lemon

After inserting Kumquat. inserted? 1
Fig
Apple
Lemon
Kumquat
```

Comment: thanks for explanation, I just want to clarify this part    ........                     (a.size() == b.size() && a.compare(b) < 0) .. whats the significance of calling a.compare(b)?

Comment: `std::string::compare` compares two `std::string`s and returns 0 if they are equal, otherwise it returns -1 if `this` is considered lexically `<` the string passed as an argument, which generally amounts to an alphabetical comparison. e.g. `string("a").compare("b")` returns -1 whereas `string("b").compare("a")` returns 1 and `string("a").compare("a")` returns 0.

Answer (score 4):

A [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) can not contain duplicates. In this case it can't have two strings the same length. Perhaps you would do better using a [std::multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct compare {
    bool operator() (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const{
        return a.size() < b.size();
    }
};

template<typename T>
void print(const T& t){
    for(auto& it : t)
        std::cout << it << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string word;
    std::multiset<std::string, compare> c; // multiset!!!

    while(std::cin >> word)
        c.insert(word);

    print(c);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Fig
Pear
Apple
Lemon
Durian
Prunes
Avocado
Kumquat
Apricots
Watermelon
Raspberries
Strawberries
Tangerine/Clementine
```

**NOTE:** This solution allows duplicate string lengths so that strings can be sorted by length. But that means it also allows duplicate string values so that the very same string can appear more than once.

Comment: This depends on OP's requirements. If "normal" duplicates should still be ignored (ie, inserting "Pear" twice), a multiset won't work.

Comment: @Galik thanks, this is also a possible solution. is their any other differences of the two aside from duplicates?

Comment: @XDProgrammer Other than duplicates? Not that I can think of. The interfaces are remarkably similar.

Comment: @alecb Yes I don't have a solution for that so I have noted it as a limitation.

Answer (score 3):

Sets don't allow duplicate elements. If the set's comparison function is `less`, then the set uses `!less(a, b) && !less(b, a)` to determine if two elements are the same (and thus duplicates).

By default, the comparison function a set uses is the `<` operator. So when you do:

```
set::set<int> s;
int x = 42, y = 42;
s.insert(x);
s.insert(y);
```

The reason only one element gets inserted is because `x < y` is false and `y < x` is also false, so the set determines that `x == y` and ignores the second insert.

But by the comparison function you've defined, all strings of the same length are considered the same. Once a string of length `N` exists in the set, all future strings of length `N` you try and insert will not be inserted (because the set thinks they're already there).

```
std::set<string, compare> s;
s.insert("abc");
s.insert("def");
```

`less("abc", "def")` is false and `less("def", "abc")` is false, so the set interprets `"abc"` and `"def"` as being the same.

You can work around this by using a tie-breaking `less` function, like:

```
bool operator() (const string& a, const string& b) const{
    if (a.size() == b.size()) {
      return a < b;
    }
    return a.size() < b.size();
}
```

This will sort strings by size first, but break ties by sorting lexicographically. Now two strings won't be considered equal unless they're actually the same.

Comment: So set does not allow to insert same elements that specified in the compare?

Comment: thanks, this works exactly as what i want to do. So the purpose of the second parameter on set is to compare elements and exclude them? Perphaps I dont clearly understand what the second parameter does..

Comment: @XDProgrammer It serves two purposes: 1) To determine a sort order for the elements in the set, 2) To provide a way of checking whether two elements are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Have you noticed that all your entries in the set have different lengths?

That's because the `compare` function dictates whether something is considered a duplicate of what's already in the set:

> Two elements of a set are considered equivalent if key_comp returns false reflexively (i.e., no matter the order in which the elements are passed as arguments).

Since, for two words of the same length, both `key_comp(word1, word2)` and `key_comp(word2, word1)` return false, the words are considered identical and the second is therefore not inserted into the set.

You can fix this with a slight modification to your function:

```
bool operator() (const string& a, const string& b) const {
    if (a.size() == b.size()) return a < b;
    return a.size() < b.size();
}
```

which performs a content-based comparison (rather than length-based) where the two items are of the same length).

Comment: thanks for clarification. how does string being compared if you compare them directly. in the solution you compare a < b , are they still compared by size, even without explicitly calling the .size() function?

Comment: The default `<` operator for strings compares them lexicographically (alphabetically).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't particularly care about the most efficient solution, and only care about the order of insertion. Here is a simple solution: sort then insert.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::set<std::string> InsertByLength(std::vector<std::string> src)
{
  std::sort(src.begin(), src.end(), [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
            {
            return a.size() < b.size();
            });

  std::set<std::string> ret;
  for(auto s : src) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    ret.insert(s);
  }

  return ret;
}

int main()
{
  auto result = InsertByLength({
    "Apple", "Apricots", "Avocado", "Durian", "Fig", "Tangerine/Clementine",
    "Kumquat", "Lemon", "Pear", "Prunes"  "Raspberries", "Strawberries",
    "Watermelon"});

  std::cout << "Inserted: " << result.size() << " elements\n";

  return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/d1T0ew